# getting entity Model from List of base entity

Tags: list, model, radix

I have an abstract base type

public abstract class Base{
some fields.... here...
}

I have lot of models in project. Current functionality is with only one model.
Suppose he want to save some xxx model into database he can simple send that as base entity model and getting each field and save into database.

But I have to save bulk entities so  I have define like List. I can able to send that list of entities into repository class .

In reporistory class I have code for converting xxx model into xml file. So I am able to send this as list of base entities but I am not able to figure out how can i convert this as xxx model. Currently it is converted all fields which is available in Base abstract class .

in My client I have the below code
client.cs file

```
List<Base> obj=new List<Base>();
foreach(xxx xyz in listofxxxmodel)
{
   obj.add(xyz);
}
```

entityresponse=repositroy.SavebulkEntities(obj);

Repository.cs

```
public response SavebulkEntities(List<obj> obj)
{
   //Here i required the this is xxx model...
   I can able to convert this now like below..
   List<xxx> xxxobj=new List<xxx>();
   foreach(xxx xx1 in obj)
   {
       xxxiobj.add(xx1);
   }
   string xml=convet(xx1);
}
```

Here Repository.cs is a genaric class ,So I can't able to hard code xxx model. Is it possible to get the specificModel without hard coded?

Comment: any pointers on this